# Showing Product Options (upsells and freebies) in the sales order grid

Tags: magento

Hello The Great Developers,

I want to customize the sales order Grid.
currently several product options are added when ever the product is added to the cart.
and they are showing up in the Order detail page in the admin panel.
but i want to make it show up in the Sales order grid.

and if i made a join query to show the product options from the sales_flat_order_item table, it is showing php array string in the serialized form which is unreadable. looks like json string.

I have been working on this issue from the past 2 days but haven't got any proper solution for this.

Your help will be fully appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a custom module...
read more http://tutorials.slcdev.com/2012/04/magento-extend-order-grid/ or http://inchoo.net/ecommerce/magento/how-to-extend-magento-order-grid/

In app/code/local/RWS/OrderGridOptions/etc/config.xml

```
<global>
    <blocks>
       <adminhtml>
          <rewrite>
              <sales_order_grid>RWS_OrderGridOptions_Block_Adminhtml_Sales_Order_Grid</sales_order_grid>
          </rewrite>
       </adminhtml>
    </blocks>
</global>
```

Create in app/code/local/RWS/OrderGridOptions/Block/Adminhtml/Sales/Order/Grid.php

(see app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Sales/Order/Grid.php)

create function _prepareColumns()

```
$this->addColumn('product_options', array(
    'header'    => Mage::helper('order')->__('Options'),
    'width'     => '150',
    'index'     => 'product_options'
    'renderer' = new RWS_OrderGridOptions_Block_Adminhtml_Renderer_Data()  // added this line
));
```

Read more @ http://www.magentocommerce.com/boards/viewthread/192232/#t239222

in app/code/local/RWS/OrderGridOptions/Block/Adminhtml/Renderer/Data.php

```
class RWS_OrderGridOptions_Block_Adminhtml_Renderer_Data extends Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Grid_Column_Renderer_Action
 {
    public function render(Varien_Object $row)
     {
         return $this->_getValue($row);
     }

     public function _getValue(Varien_Object $row)
     {
         $val = $row->getData($this->getColumn()->getIndex());  // row value
         $array = unserialize($val);

         //loop thru the $array and create a format string 
         //
         $format_val = $array['xyx'] . ' ' . $array['abc'];

         return $format_val;


     }

 }
```

Comment: oh Thank You so much R.S.. Your trick really worked for me. i was frustrated with this problem from the past 3 days. and you have really helped me a lot. Thanx a lot

Answer (score 0):

I followed the code @R.S s with the following modifications to the renderer out more user friendly:

```
 public function render(Varien_Object $row)
{
    return $this->_getValue($row);
}
public function _getValue(Varien_Object $row)
{
    $codeIndex = $row->getData($this->getColumn()->getIndex());  // row value

    $prodOpUns = unserialize($codeIndex);

    $dataOpt = $prodOpUns['options'];

    $returnHtml = '<dl class="item-options">';

    for ($i=0; $i<count($dataOpt); $i++){

        $value = str_replace(array("&lt;", "&gt;"), array("<", ">"), htmlspecialchars($dataOpt[$i]['print_value'], ENT_COMPAT, "UTF-8", false));

        $returnHtml .= '<dt>'.strtolower($dataOpt[$i]['label']) .'</dt>' . '<dd>' . $value . '</dd>';
    }

    $returnHtml .= '</dl>';

    return $returnHtml;

}
```